# Find the voltage Vab and current of the circuit I

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

[image]

I was asked to find the voltage  Vab and the current of the circuit I.

I tried finding the voltage in ab using voltage divider, but I have two voltage sources and I don't know how to make the respective formula

A voltage divider is  E*(R1/R1+R2) for the respective place you want to measure, but what about when there are two voltage sources?

I'd like to ask for some guidance as to where I am supposed to look or how to start. As for the current of the circuit, maybe finding an Rtotal and then using two Ohm's law?

Comment: Just by simple visual inspection, Vab = 14 volts. Use your eyes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your eyes and very simply, write down the numbers for voltages and the currents defined by ohm's law: -

[image]

I think your big mistake is not recognizing that ground (shown in green) connects to the 6 volt source and the 5 ohm resistor. Do not launch into anything mathematical until you understand the diagram and it is simplified.

So, quite literally the voltage at node a becomes -6 volts and, the voltage at node b becomes -20 volts (just by visual inspection). These voltages define the current of 7 amps flowing through the 2 Ω resistor.

Node b being at -20 volts also defines the current through the 5 Ω resistor being 4 amps. The 7 amps and the 4 amps tell you that 11 amps flows through the 20 volt battery.

-6 volts across the 3 Ω resistor means there is 2 amps flowing in it.

And finally, you should be able to see why the 5 amps flows in the 6 volt battery. This bit is down to you.

Simple visual inspection of the circuit and ohms law.

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework problems.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it's a tricky one. The OP said in his post this: *i have two voltage sources and i dont know how to make the respective formula* and this told me he wasn't looking at the problem correctly so I solved it "visually" but, you are right so, I'll withdraw a couple of things in my answer.